# Intervention Image Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to resize img, I do this step:
update composer:

```
"intervention/image": "dev-master",
```

next add lines in app/config

```
     Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
    'Image'     => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

In my controller:

```
use Intervention\Image\Image as Img;
Img::make($destination_path . $filename)->resize(200, 200)->save($destination_path . $filename);
```

and this is error:

```
Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\Image::make()
```

All In laravel 5.1

Comment: try replacing your code in the controller with just `Image::make(.....` Your facade should make the Image class available, if not then do `\Image::make(...` instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

1) check if you have model in your App (by default) folder named as Image

2)

a) put `use Image;` to the top of your controller

b) throw this away: use Intervention\Image\Image as Img;

c) just use this: `Image::make(` not Img:make(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem myself. After a lot of googling, I found [this tutorial](http://devartisans.com/articles/resize-images-laravel5.1) specific for Laravel 5.1.

Simply change

```
use Intervention\Image\Image;
```

to

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

Comment: then it says this `ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class image does not exist`

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the below Steps:

1) Open composer.json file from your root directory

```
      "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",

        // add these lines
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master"
    }
```

2) Now run composer update command to get those packages.

```
 composer update
```

3) Open config/app.php file

a) update the providers array with the following line.

```
     'providers' => [

        // add this line at the bottom  
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
        ]
```

b) update the aliases array with the following line.

```
'aliases' => [
         // add this line at the bottom 
        'Image'     => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
        ],
```

4) You are done!

See details here: http://www.pranms.com/intervention-image-integration-in-laravel/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to use facade instead of provider.
So instead of:

```
use Intervention\Image\Image as Img;
```

just put this:

```
use Image;
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
Image::make($destination_path . $filename)->resize(200, 200)->save($destination_path . $filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open : config/app.php

Add to array aliases :

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::class,
```

In Controller :

```
use Image;
```